# Removing spaces from citations in BibLatex

Tags: biblatex, spacing, citing

I am using BibLaTeX to organize my references. I use it in the following way:

```latex
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=numeric,doi=false,maxbibnames=99,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

However, when I cite several authors, eg.

```latex
\cite{author1,author2,author3}
```

the results is: `[10, 11, 12]`.

How can I remove the spaces between the numbers? Also, how could I set it to `[10-12]` instead of `[10, 11, 12]`?

Comment: Try with numeric-comp instead of numeric.

Comment: And ideally you should be using `biber` as the backend, not `bibtex8`.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of the space try `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma}` but I have my doubts that this makes your citations easier to read.